# Removing node from JSF TreeModel tree?

Tags: java, jsf, tree, oracle-adf, treemodel

I have faced some problems with removing node from JSF [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E18745_01/apidocs/oracle/adf/view/faces/model/TreeModel.html) tree. Is it possible to somehow remove node from TreeModel object?

Please see snippet below:

```
TreeModel treeModel = getModel();
for (int j = 0; j < treeModel.getRowCount(); j++) {
            MyTreeNode node = (MyTreeNode)treeModel.getRowData(j);
            if (node.needsRemoval()) {
            }
        }
```

Your assistance is very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer - TreeModel extends DataModel class, which is abstraction around data collection provided in *setWrappedData()* method. So as far as I understood, there is no way to change tree model nodes, however you can tamper with data collection and reattach it with *setWrappedData()*. Please let me know if I am wrong.